# moz-selection not working on Firefox

Tags: css

My css:

```
::selection, ::-moz-selection {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    background: #404040;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

It works on Chrome, but on Firefox it still has the default blue background.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do it separate commands:

See here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection

```
 ::selection{
    color: #f2f2f2;
    background: #404040;
    text-shadow: none;
}
 ::-moz-selection {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    background: #404040;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```